# How to install Wacom Intous 4 driver?

Tags: drivers, input-devices, wacom, graphics-tablet

I did a lot of searches on Google in how to install [Intous 4](http://www.wacom.com/intuos/) driver, but I couldn't find anything that worked until now.

I am looking for step by step installation tutorial to install the driver.

and how can i check that everything is configured correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install the latest driver (both kernel and xorg parts) shown in this help file:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom/LatestDriver

For example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wacom-dkms xserver-xorg-input-wacom
```

This should install the latest driver for both maverick and lucid. If this doesn't work then let me know and I will look into upstream and if needed, update this driver for you.

Comment: thanks alot in protest, now the pen is working but the LED is not , is their a way to let LED works and to check if the driver is working correctly ?

Comment: What function does the LED do for you?

Comment: it just give indication to what every button next to the LED do .

Comment: If it doesn't work then it's probably an upstream issue, can you report the issue here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=525124&group_id=69596&func=browse